# Javascript: fetch values from textbox of a dynamic datagrid. (skipping some textboxes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dynamic-data

i have seen similar questions to this but none can assist me.as my code is missing some results and i don't now why.

[image]

as seen on the image above the output is 6 results instead of 12

This is the code am using to get the values

```
            //Fetch Sales**********************************************
            function fetchsales(){
            var Dt = document.getElementById("sDate").value;
            var Usr = document.getElementById("UserID").value;
            var Stp = document.getElementById("tstamp").value;
            var e = document.getElementById("sdepot");
            var Dpt = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            var sale = new Array();

            var Tbl = document.getElementById('tbl_sales'); //html table
            var tbody = Tbl.tBodies[0];    // Optional, based on what is rendered
            for (var i = 2; i < tbody.rows.length; i++) {
            var row = tbody.rows[i];
            for (var j = 2; j < row.cells.length; j++) {
            var cell = row.cells[j];

            // For Every Cell get the textbox value
            var unitsold = cell.childNodes[0].value ;
            //Get selectbox distributor
            var Sdist = row.cells[1].childNodes[0]; //Select box always on second coloumn
            var Distributor = Sdist.options[Sdist.selectedIndex].value;
            //Get selectbox Product
            var Sprod = tbody.rows[1].cells[j].childNodes[0];
            var Product = Sprod.options[Sprod.selectedIndex].value;

            sale[(j*i)] = new Array ('('+Dt,Dpt,Product,unitsold,Distributor,Usr,Stp+')<br/>');

            }
            }

            //Debug
            var fsale = new Array();
            fsale = sale.filter(function(n){return n});
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = fsale;
            }
            //End Fetch Sales******************************************************
```

And this is the Whole Document with the Above code included.

```
                <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <head>
                <style>

                </style>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                //*********************************Start Add Row **********************************************************
                function addRowToTable() {
                var tbl = document.getElementById('tbl_sales'); //html table
                var columnCount = tbl.rows[0].cells.length; //no. of columns in table 
                var rowCount = tbl.rows.length; //no. of rows in table 
                var row = tbl.insertRow(rowCount); //insert a row method

                // For Every Row Added a Checkbox on first cell--------------------------------------
                var cell_1 = row.insertCell(0); //Create a new cell
                var element_1 = document.createElement("input"); //create a new element
                element_1.type = "checkbox"; //set element type
                element_1.setAttribute('id', 'newCheckbox'); //set id attribute
                cell_1.appendChild(element_1); //Append element to created cell

                // For Every Row Added add a Select box on Second cell------------------------------
                var cell_2 = row.insertCell(1);
                var element_2 = document.createElement('select');
                element_2.name = 'SelDist' + rowCount;
                element_2.className = 'styled-select';
                element_2.options[0] = new Option('John Doe', '1');
                element_2.options[1] = new Option('Dane Doe', '2');
                cell_2.appendChild(element_2);

                // For Every Row Added add a textbox on the rest of the cells starting with the 3rd,4th,5th...  coloumns going on...
                if (columnCount >= 2) { //Add cells for more than 2 columns
                for (var i = 3; i <= columnCount; i++) {
                var newCel = row.insertCell(i - 1); //create a new cell           
                var element_3 = document.createElement("input");
                element_3.type = "text";
                element_3.className = "rounded";
                element_3.name = 'txt_r'+ rowCount +'c'+(i-1);
                element_3.id = 'txt_r'+ rowCount +'c'+(i-1);  
                element_3.size = 5;  
                element_3.value = 'txt_r'+rowCount+'c'+(i-1); 
                newCel.appendChild(element_3);
                }
                }
                }
                //***************************** End Add Row ***************************************************************
                // *****************************Start Add Column**********************************************************
                function addColumn() {
                var tblBodyObj = document.getElementById('tbl_sales').tBodies[0];
                var rowCount = tblBodyObj.rows.length;

                //for every Coloumn Added Add checkbox on first row ----------------------------------------------
                var newchkbxcell = tblBodyObj.rows[0].insertCell(-1);
                var element_4 = document.createElement("input");
                element_4.type = "checkbox";
                element_4.setAttribute('id', 'newCheckbox');
                newchkbxcell.appendChild(element_4);

                //For Every Coloumn Added add Drop down list on second row-------------------------------------
                var newselectboxcell = tblBodyObj.rows[1].insertCell(-1);
                var element_5 = document.createElement('select');
                element_5.name = 'SelProd' + rowCount;
                element_5.className = 'styled-select';
                element_5.options[0] = new Option('Product11', '11');
                element_5.options[1] = new Option('Product12', '12');
                element_5.options[2] = new Option('Product13', '13');
                element_5.options[3] = new Option('Product14', '14');
                element_5.options[4] = new Option('Product15', '15');
                element_5.options[5] = new Option('Product16', '16');

                newselectboxcell.appendChild(element_5);

                // For Every Coloumn Added add a textbox on the rest of the row cells starting with the 3rd,4th,5th......  
                for (var i = 2; i < tblBodyObj.rows.length; i++) { //Add cells in all rows starting with 3rd row
                var newCell = tblBodyObj.rows[i].insertCell(-1); //create new cell
                var ClmCount = ((tblBodyObj.rows[0].cells.length)-1); 
                var element_6 = document.createElement("input");
                element_6.type = "text";
                element_6.className = "rounded"
                element_6.name = 'txt_r'+ i + 'c' + ClmCount;
                element_6.id = 'txt_r'+ i + 'c' + ClmCount;  
                element_6.size = 5;  
                element_6.value = 'txt_r'+i+'c'+ClmCount;
                newCell.appendChild(element_6)
                }
                }
                //*****************************Start Delete Selected Rows **************************************************
                function deleteSelectedRows() {
                var tb = document.getElementById('tbl_sales');
                var NoOfrows = tb.rows.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < NoOfrows; i++) {
                var row = tb.rows[i];
                var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0]; //get check box object               
                if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) { //wheather check box is selected                   
                tb.deleteRow(i); //delete the selected row                    
                NoOfrows--; //decrease rowcount by 1                   
                i--;
                }
                }
                }
                //*****************************End Delete Selected Columns **************************************************
                //*****************************Start Delete Selected Columns ************************************************
                function deleteSelectedColoumns() {
                var tb = document.getElementById('tbl_sales'); //html table
                var NoOfcolumns = tb.rows[0].cells.length; //no. of columns in table 
                for (var clm = 3; clm < NoOfcolumns; clm++) {
                var rw = tb.rows[0]; //0th row with checkboxes
                var chkbox = rw.cells[clm].childNodes[0];
                console.log('Current Coloumn:'+clm+',', NoOfcolumns, chkbox); // test with Ctrl+Shift+K or F12
                if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                //-----------------------------------------------------
                var lastrow = tb.rows;
                for (var x = 0; x < lastrow.length; x++) {
                tb.rows[x].deleteCell(clm);
                }
                //----------------------------------------- 
                NoOfcolumns--;
                clm--;
                } else {
                //alert("not selected");
                }
                }
                }
                //*****************************End Delete Selected Columns **************************************************


                //Fetch Sales**********************************************
                function fetchsales(){
                var Dt = document.getElementById("sDate").value;
                var Usr = document.getElementById("UserID").value;
                var Stp = document.getElementById("tstamp").value;
                var e = document.getElementById("sdepot");
                var Dpt = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
                var sale = new Array();

                var Tbl = document.getElementById('tbl_sales'); //html table
                var tbody = Tbl.tBodies[0];    // Optional, based on what is rendered
                for (var i = 2; i < tbody.rows.length; i++) {
                var row = tbody.rows[i];
                for (var j = 2; j < row.cells.length; j++) {
                var cell = row.cells[j];

                // For Every Cell get the textbox value
                var unitsold = cell.childNodes[0].value ;
                //Get selectbox distributor
                var Sdist = row.cells[1].childNodes[0]; //Select box always on second coloumn
                var Distributor = Sdist.options[Sdist.selectedIndex].value;
                //Get selectbox Product
                var Sprod = tbody.rows[1].cells[j].childNodes[0];
                var Product = Sprod.options[Sprod.selectedIndex].value;

                sale[(j*i)] = new Array ('('+Dt,Dpt,Product,unitsold,Distributor,Usr,Stp+')<br/>');

                }
                }

                //Debug
                var fsale = new Array();
                fsale = sale.filter(function(n){return n});
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = fsale;
                }
                //End Fetch Sales******************************************************     
                //on loading create 3 coloumns and 2 rows
                window.onload = function () {addColumn();addColumn();addColumn();addRowToTable();addRowToTable();}; 
                </script>

                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                <title>Distributor Sales</title>
                </head>

                <body>
                <!--A--->
                <div class="datagrid shadow" style="float:left; min-width:160px; width:220px">
                <table  id="top">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td width="100px">
                <label for="textfield2">Date</label>
                <input id="sDate" name="sDate" type="date" size="10" class="rounded" value="2013-06-04" />
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="alt">
                <td width="220px">
                <label for="select">Depot</label>
                <select name="sdepot" id="sdepot" class="styled-select">
                <option value="1">Muranga</option>
                <option value="2" selected="selected">Nyahururu</option>
                <option value="3">Karatina</option>
                </select>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
                <!--C--->
                <div class="datagrid shadow" style="float:left; margin-left:20px; width:250px; min-width:250px">
                <table>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>
                <label for="textfield4">User ID</label>
                <input id="UserID" name="UserID" type="text" class="rounded" value="121" />
                </td>

                </tr>
                <tr class="alt">
                <td>

                <label for="textfield5">Time Stamp</label>
                <input type="date" name="tstamp" id="tstamp" class="rounded" value="2013-06-02" />
                </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
                </br>
                <div class="mainG gradient-style shadow"  style="min-width:500px; min-height:120px">  
                <table id="tbl_sales" border="1" bordercolor="#E1EEF4" background="table-images/blurry.jpg">
                <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="button3" id="button3" value="-Row" onclick="deleteSelectedRows()" />
                <input type="button" name="button4" id="button4" value="-Coloumn" onclick="deleteSelectedColoumns()" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="addrowbutton" id="adrwbutton" value="+Row" onclick="addRowToTable();" />
                <input type="button" name="adclmbutton" id="addclmnbutton" value="+Coloumn" onclick="addColumn()" />
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </div> 
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
                <br/>
                <div class="datagrid shadow" style="float:left; margin-left:20px; width:200px; min-width:200px; padding-left:10px">
                <table id="bottom1" style="min-width:200px">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>
                <div align="center"><input name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Save Information" onClick="javascript:fetchsales();">
                </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
                <br/>
                <div id="output"></div>
                </body>
                </html>
```

NB: am hoping to concatenate the result to a mysql insert statement

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from this line:

```
sale[(j*i)] = new Array ('('+Dt,Dpt,Product,unitsold,Distributor,Usr,Stp+')<br/>');
```

using the for loops indexes multiplied by themselves doesnt ensure unique array indexes, in some cases they are repeated (like for example 2*3 and 3*2) and the previous value in the array gets overwritten.

Comment: Thanks for the insight i had not realized that.i tried replacing the indexes with the variables 'i' and 'j' from the loops,but it still did not work out.i am using several tutorials.to construct the code,any advice on how i should rectify the code?

Comment: you could simply use the push method instead of using indexes:

    sale.push(new Array ('('+Dt,Dpt,Product,unitsold,Distributor,Usr,Stp+')<br/>'));

Comment: It works perfectly.thanks alot for the assistance.Now that am not so experienced i had been at it for hours.